# How to add a banner or a text message in every post with PHP, using WordPress Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

that what i want to do is to add a banner or  text message before post and a second banner or a  text message after post, how i can add this with php in WordPress?

Example:

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: 
Plugin URI:  
Description:  
Version:  
Author:  
Author URI:  
Text Domain: 
Domain Path:
*/
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

add_action("the_content", function($content) { return "<p>Bla bla bla</p>".$content."<p>Lorem ispum</p>"; });

?>
```

Comment: for  that you have to customize single.php in current theme.

Comment: You can also used a hook on "the_content". (functions.php)
`add_action("the_content", function($content) { return "<p>Bla bla bla</p>".$content."<p>Lorem ispum</p>"; });`

Comment: Thanks for your help, is posible to add this function from Plugin?

Comment: i have edit my question, and i have add your code, Pleas, can you show me how to add that code in WordPress Plugin? Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted? That should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
<?php
function theme_slug_filter_the_content( $content ) {
    $custom_content = 'YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE';
    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content' );
?>
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more details visit,
[WordPress hooks/filters insert before content or after title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39918/wordpress-hooks-filters-insert-before-content-or-after-title)